# Resizing images on canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have the following code:

https://jsfiddle.net/8o3sn9mh/17/

```
<canvas id='c' style='position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;'>
</canvas>

<script>
var
canvas = document.getElementById('c'),
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var flower = new Image();
flower.src = "http://plainicon.com/dboard/userprod/2803_dd580/prod_thumb/plainicon.com-46129-128px-af2.png"
flower.onload = function(){
ctx.drawImage(flower,0,0,128,128, 0, 0, 30, 30);
ctx.drawImage(flower,0,0,128,128, 0, 0, 218, 218);
</script>
```

Short story: as you can see the flower doesn't resize well, it's quality is lost.

Long story:

I am making a game with shapes. basically, I use image with ratios such as 128-128 or 80-80 since its designed for phones, and I make sure when I resize the images to keep that 1:1 ratio. With calculations based on the user's window, I decide how much to resize the images proportionally since the canvas is on full screen. It works decent on some screen but on some it doesn't - the images can downscale too much and look poor or upscale too much and look unclear. it is most noticeable on triangle images(I know I can draw pure shapes with canvas but I need to draw faces on them so it is impossible). Any good method to do nicely?

Answer (score 0):

That is the nature of pixel based images.

When downscaling try to keep the image sizes whole ratios, it will improve the quality.

Eg you have 128, then you reduce it to 30, that means pixels are reduced by  128/30 = 4.2666. Pixels are discrete units of information and can not easily be cut into smaller units without loss of quality.

If you changed the size to 32 pixels 128/32 = 4 you get better quality because you are not cutting up any pixels.

For upscaling there is little you can do, Its either blurry or pixelated. Your source images should always be at a higher resolution than you need. Rule of thumb is "only downscale".

If the quality of the images downscaled with whole ratios is not to your liking then the best option is do the scaling in production on photoshop (or the like), then let the device select which images to download. This will give you the best possible quality for all devices and save you and the users some bandwidth (for smaller res devices)

Comment: But I have no idea how many versions of each image to make, and when to choose one over the other.

Comment: @user1938653 You make a lot, you can automate the task. You store them in directories or with post-fixes according to device resolution. You can also have the server run a high quality downscale for images when a device logs on and has a resolution you have not yet encountered. Or you accept that some devices will not have perfect image quality, the fault is the device not yours. Get your game out there, then address the problem of quirky devices as you will never cover all possibilities before release